# How to write functional Test with spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark batch job that talks with cassandra. After the batch job gets completed , I need to verify few entries in cassandra and the cycle continues for 2-3 times. How do I know when the batch job ends ? I don't want to track the status of batch job by adding entry in db.

How to write functional test in spark ?